# Is it possible to assign chunks of Json to another Json using Liquid Transform in Logic Apps

Tags: json, transform, liquid, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to assign chunks of Json to another Json object using Liquid Transform in Logic Apps?
The sample input json to the Transform would looks like this

```
{
    "person": {
        "name": "john",
        "age": 20
    }
}
```

The liquid map would look something like this

```
{
"output":{{content.person}}
}
```

The expected output would look like this

```
{
    "output": {
        "person": {
            "name": "john",
            "age": 20
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How's going? has your issue been solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[image]

Content of `stantest` map:

```
{"output":{{content}}}
```

Result of this logic App:

[image]